# MongoDB strange behaviour, orOperator

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongodb-query

I use  spring mongodb  java API. I have a question regarding `orOperator`.
When I use such criteria, I get `null`.

```
 Criteria c1 = Criteria.where(field2).regex("John", "i");
 Criteria c2 = Criteria.where(field1).regex("John", "i");
 new Criteria().orOperator(c1, c1);
```

Whereas using gives what I expected.

```
new Criteria().andOperator(c1, c1);
```

I am a little bit confused, cause from Bool'e logic, when I say `1` or `1` i should get `1`. Do you have any reasoning behind that?

Just want to add that using the following produces the expected result.

```
new Criteria().orOperator(c1);
```

Comment: Is it a typo new Criteria().andOperator(c1, c1); ? 
Shouldn't it be new Criteria().andOperator(c1, c2);

Comment: Nope, I am wondering why I got null, when I use `orOperator` with same double criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Ex: Get any user

```
  query.addCriteria(
        Criteria.where("role").is("user")
          .orOperator(Criteria.where("role").is("manager"))
            .orOperator(Criteria.where("role").is("admin"))
  );
```

Note: By name it is *Operator* not an Operation.